# RazorPages Page Remote not working on model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, remote-validation

as per https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/343/improved-remote-validation-in-razor-pages
I followed the tutorial and implemented the PageRemote. However it does not work if applied to a property of a model and I use the model as property.

```
public class Draft
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [PageRemote(ErrorMessage = "Invalid data", AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken", HttpMethod = "post", PageHandler = "CheckReference")]
    public string Reference { get; set; }

}

[BindProperty]
public Draft Draft { get; set; }

public JsonResult OnPostCheckReference()
{            
    var valid = !Draft.Reference.Contains("12345");
    return new JsonResult(valid);
}
```

on my page

```
<tab>
    <tab-item icon="fas fa-arrow-left" url="@Url.Page("../Index")"></tab-item>
    <tab-item icon="fas fa-list" url="@Url.Page("Index")"></tab-item>
    <tab-item icon="fas fa-plus" is-active="true"></tab-item>
</tab>
<form method="post">
    <card>
        <card-header icon="fas fa-plus" title="Draft"></card-header>
        <card-body>

            <input asp-for="Draft.Reference" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Draft.Reference" class="text-danger"></span>

        </card-body>
        <card-footer>
            <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Adicionar </button>
        </card-footer>
    </card>
</form>
@section Scripts{

    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remote validation on nested model properties is not straightforward. The framework prefixes all additional fields with the name of the model, so request verification fails, resulting in a 400 error.

The work around is to separate the field that you want to validate remotely from the sub-model, and make it a first class property of the PageModel instead. Then, if ModelState is valid, assign the value to the nested model.

```
public class Draft
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }

}

[BindProperty]
public Draft Draft { get; set; }

[BindProperty, PageRemote(ErrorMessage = "Invalid data", AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken", HttpMethod = "post", PageHandler = "CheckReference")]
public string Reference {get;set;}

public JsonResult OnPostCheckReference()
{            
    var valid = !Reference.Contains("12345");
    return new JsonResult(valid);
}
```

Then in the form:

```
<input asp-for="Reference" />
<span asp-validation-for="Reference" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Comment: I see, i tried this before just to test and it worked but i wasn't aware this was the case of the framework. Thanks for clearing it up

Answer (score 5):

Remote validation on nested model properties doesn't allow you to specify additional fields on a parent object. The `__RequestVerificationToken` is always on the root of the model. The source for [jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/blob/master/src/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js) is looking for fields prefixed with `*.` and prefixes the model name to them. The `asp-for` tag helper is adding `*.` to the beginning of the fields.

You can circumvent this prefixing of `*.` by manually specifying the attribute in html and removing AdditionalFields from the attribute.

PageRemoteAttribute:

```
public class Draft
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [PageRemote(ErrorMessage = "Invalid data", HttpMethod = "post", PageHandler = "CheckReference")]
    public string Reference { get; set; }

}
```

Html:

```
<input asp-for="Reference" data-val-remote-additionalfields="__RequestVerificationToken" />
```

Comment: Thank you! This is by far the easiest way I have seen to tackle the key issue.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this answer.
But I have another problem and can't find any info on that. What If the developer needed to add the Draft.ID as a parameter to the PageRemote attribute? My case is very similar, as I also have a View model and an inner property to validate, but it also requires another property. Taking this case as example, I've tried passing the id parameter with AdditionalFields = "Draft.ID" or even AdditionalFields = "ID", but it is not being posted together with the Draft.Reference when the post handler is triggered

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in 10/2023, but was immensely helpful in finding a solution. The `data-val-remote-addtionalfields` gets overwritten in .Net 7. I had to write a small JS file that selects all elements with `data-val-remote-additionalfields` and replaces the value. I found that the script had to be placed before the unobtrusive validation scripts in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above where you specify the `data-val-remote-additionalfields` attribute directly on the input appears to no longer work for .Net 7. The tag builders seem to be overwriting the value and putting `*.` in front. This happens whether additional fields are specified in the data annotation or not.

Since I couldn't figure out a way to control the output via annotations and attributes, I wrote a simple script to find all inputs with the `data-val-remote-additionalfields` attribute and strips out the prefix for the request verification token.

We still use jquery because the FluentValidation clientside adapters rely on it. This script uses the `$(function(){})` short-hand to run when the DOM is ready. You can easily replace it with a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener. The rest is Vanilla JS.

```
$(function () {
    var remoteValidators = document.querySelectorAll('[data-val-remote-additionalfields]');
    if (remoteValidators) {
        remoteValidators.forEach(val => {
            var value = val.getAttribute('data-val-remote-additionalfields');
            value = value.replace('*.__RequestVerificationToken', '__RequestVerificationToken');
            val.setAttribute('data-val-remote-additionalfields', value);
        });
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** This script needs to be placed after jQuery, but before the validation libraries.